# center text in div like an img element

Tags: html, css

I can center fixed images easily on the page, but when it comes to text it seems to be more complex. this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rc9fa/353/) demonstrates how the image is centered but the text is not. How can I center the text in the same way? Thanks for reading.

```
.center{
         display:table;
         position:fixed;
         left:0;
         right:0;
         margin:auto;
         border:1px solid grey;
}

<div class = "center">text</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rc9fa/357/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a width and use `text-align:center`  http://jsfiddle.net/Rc9fa/358/

```
.center{
width:100px;
text-align:center;
display:table;
position:fixed;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
border:1px solid grey;

}
```

Comment: @Danko He will have to change class or use multiple classes then

Comment: This is a good solution however, the width is variable, so if the div is more than 100px,it will no longer be centered. Thanks for the answer. +1

Comment: @user2014429 i will look into it later i have to go its getting late

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to figure it out. It can be done with relative position, but I need it to be fixed really. No hurry. :)

Comment: this works greats. cute Kitten picture. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

Just add `text-align:center;` and `width:100%;` to your css. Is this what you are looking for?

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kirito/Rc9fa/355/)

**EDIT:** You can replace `width:100%;` with `width:yourWidthYouWant;` and it will work as well.